# How to get embedded document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I tried to get embedded documents in the table using mongodb but its not working.

**dev table**

```
[{
"id":1,
"data":[{"id":1,"name":true},{"id":2,"name":true},{"id":3,"name":false},{"id":1,"name":true}]
}]
```

**Query**

```
db.dev,find({data.name:true})
```

**Excepted output**

```
[{
"id":1,
"data":[{"id":1,"name":true},{"id":2,"name":true}]
}]
```

**I got Output**

```
[{
"id":1,
"data":[{"id":1,"name":true},{"id":2,"name":true},{"id":3,"name":"false"},{"id":1,"name":true}]
}]
```

How to write the query to match the expected output. can give sample code

Comment: @ Jesús Ros I tried this query   db.test.find(
    {"data.name": true}, 
    {_id: 0, data: {$elemMatch: {name: true}}});.  
BUt I got only single record ouput :
[{
id:1
data:[{
"id":1,
"name": true
}]
}],
I need all true condition output  
[{
"id":1,
"data":[{"id":1,"name":true},{"id":2,"name":true},,{"id":1,"name":true}]
}]. How to acheive it

Answer (score -1):

Try out this solution

```
let whereClause = { "data.name":true };
    await db.dev.find(whereClause);
```