# MongoDB get all embedded documents where condition is met

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I did this in my mongodb:

```
db.teams.insert({name:"Alpha team",employees:[{name:"john"},{name:"david"}]});
db.teams.insert({name:"True team",employees:[{name:"oliver"},{name:"sam"}]});
db.teams.insert({name:"Blue team",employees:[{name:"jane"},{name:"raji"}]});
db.teams.find({"employees.name":/.*o.*/});
```

But what I got was:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ddf3ca83c182cc5354a15dd"), "name" : "Alpha team", "employees" : [ { "name" : "john" }, { "name" : "david" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ddf3ca93c182cc5354a15de"), "name" : "True team", "employees" : [ { "name" : "oliver" }, { "name" : "sam" } ] }
```

But what I really want is

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"oliver"}]
```

I'm having a hard time finding examples of this without using some kind of programmatic iterator/loop.  Or examples I find return the parent document, which means I'd have to parse out the embedded array employees and do some kind of UNION statement?

Eg.

[How to get embedded document in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815958/how-to-get-embedded-document-in-mongodb)
[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you only need array of "name" fields ? or a complete record ?

Comment: I would like the equivalent of `SELECT name FROM employees WHERE name LIKE '%o%' ORDER BY name ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add projections to filter out the fields you don't need. Please refer the project link [mongodb projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Your find query should be constructed with the projection parameters like below:

```
db.teams.find({"employees.name":/.*o.*/}, {_id:0, "employees.name": 1});
```

This will return you:

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"oliver"}]
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with my syntax for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081852/mongodb-projections-on-embedded-documents-of-embedded-documents

Comment: The query returned: `{ "employees" : [ { "name" : "john" }, { "name" : "david" } ] }
{ "employees" : [ { "name" : "oliver" }, { "name" : "sam" } ] }`.

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved with a simple aggregation pipeline.

```
db.teams.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$employees"},
    {$match : {"employees.name":/.*o.*/}},
])
```

EDIT:

OP Wants to skip the parent fields. Modified query:

```
db.teams.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$employees"},
    {$match : {"employees.name":/.*o.*/}},
    {$project : {"name":"$employees.name",_id:0}}
])
```

Output:

```
{ "name" : "john" }
{ "name" : "oliver" }
```

Comment: Your solution returns the parent document and its fields.  How do I exclude that?  or what if I said `SELECT name FROM employees WHERE name LIKE '%o%' ORDER BY name DESC`

Comment: @John you can add another `$project` to alias the result into something like: `{$project:{"name":"$employees.name",_id:0}}` and then add another process of `$sort` as `{$sort:{"name":-1}}` (*here in mongo `-1` represents descending order and 1 represents ascending order.*).