# MongoDB returne embedded documents of embedded documents without any parent documents?

Tags: mongodb

I wrote the following code in MongoDB:

```
db.departments.insert({name:"Accounting",teams:[
    {name:"Alpha team",employees:[
        {name:"john"},
        {name:"david"}
    ]},
    {name:"True team",employees:[
        {name:"oliver"},
        {name:"sam"}
    ]}
]});

db.departments.insert({name:"Engineering",teams:[
    {name:"Blue team",employees:[
        {name:"singh"},
        {name:"jane"}
    ]},
    {name:"Lazy team",employees:[
        {name:"marleen"},
        {name:"florence"}
    ]}
]});
```

I want to do the equivalent of `SELECT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%o%' ORDER BY name DESC` and get the results `[{"name":"oliver"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"florence"}]`.

I just became aware of projections, so I tried this:

```
db.departments.find({"teams.employees.name":/.*o.*/}, {_id:0, "teams.employees.name": 1}).pretty();
```

But the result was this instead:

```
{
        "teams" : [
                {
                        "employees" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "john"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "david"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "employees" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "oliver"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "sam"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "teams" : [
                {
                        "employees" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "singh"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "jane"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "employees" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "marleen"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "florence"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

What is wrong with my syntax? I am open to other suggestions to achieve my objective

Comment: `{ $unwind: "$teams" }, { $unwind: "$teams.employees" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$teams.employees" }}` https://mongoplayground.net/p/lmIfXIW3vTd

Comment: You can only achieve complex filtering using aggregation. You need to unwind all your array fields first, then project the necessary fields and then match using the regex filter.    db.departments.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$teams"},
    {$unwind: "$teams.employees"},
    {$project: {"_id":0, "name": "$teams.employees.name" }},
    {$match: {"name": {$regex: /.*o.*/ }}}
    ]) Try this and let me know the outcome

Comment: Thanks @Anban, your suggestion solved one issue, but lead to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090237/mongodb-aggregate-queries-vs-mysql-select-field1-from-table

Comment: @Ashh thanks your suggestion has solved one issue, but now lead to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090237/mongodb-aggregate-queries-vs-mysql-select-field1-from-table

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
db.departments.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$teams" },
    { $unwind: "$teams.employees" },
    { $project: { _id: 0, name: "$teams.employees.name" } },
    { $match: { "name": { $regex: /.*o.*/ }} }
]).toArray()
```

Result

```
[
    {
        "name" : "john"
    },
    {
        "name" : "oliver"
    },
    {
        "name" : "florence"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is leading to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090237/mongodb-aggregate-queries-vs-mysql-select-field1-from-table